# Problem implementing touch scroll on a container of tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a container div with some tabs, on desktop it works fine, I have this handler for it with an onMouseMove event :

```
 function dragging(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) {
    if (!filterTabsContainer.current) return;
    filterTabsContainer.current.scrollLeft -= e.movementX;
  }
```

But I need this also on mobile and movementX property doesn't exist on the onMouseTouch event object so I did this:

`let previousTouch: number = 0;`
 `let movementX: number = 0;`
`let prevScrollLeft: number = 0;`

```
function draggingTouch(e: React.TouchEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
    if (!filterTabsContainer.current) return;

    const touch = e.touches[0];

 /* this is because I need to save the value of last scrollLeft otherwise it would be back to 0 for some reason after I try to touch and drag again, the prevScrollLeft will be assigned with another handler that is for onTouchEnd;*/

    if (prevScrollLeft > 0) {
      filterTabsContainer.current.scrollLeft = prevScrollLeft - movementX;
    } else {
      filterTabsContainer.current.scrollLeft -= movementX;
    }

    if (previousTouch) {
      movementX = touch.pageX - previousTouch;
    }
    previousTouch = touch.pageX;
  }
```

It works fine when I try to drag the first time but then when I try to drag again from the position that it has been left, it doesnt' work anymore, it goes like 5px and the container remain still

Maybe there are alternatives to achieve what I want?

Comment: Could you use a `PointerEvent`? Pointer events allow handling mouse, touch and pen events simultaneously.

Comment: @sallf I tried the PointerEvent and after some tweaks it works fine, thank you